# Getting consecutive dates with the same group from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table, containing a group_id for some dates:

```
date       | group_id
2017-12-12 | 1
2017-12-14 | 1
2017-12-15 | 1
2017-12-16 | 9
2017-12-17 | 9
2017-12-24 | 1
```

Remarks: Not *every* date is in the table; for non-existing dates there is a 'default' value.

**Question:**
Given a date `$date`: how many consecutive days `$n` in the future have the same `group_id` value? (excluding the given date)

In the above table, with `$default = 1` these would be the results:

```
2017-12-12: 3 (13-default, 14 & 15)
2017-12-16: 1 (17)
```

Scaffold:

```
function getConsecutiveDays($date, $default = 1, $max = 99)
{

   //magic

   return $n;
}
```

(With `$max` to make sure there is an end somewhere, as there could be an 'open' end)

Anybody an idea how to solve this?

Comment: I don't really understand. Can you give the actual use-case for doing this? I feel like some context is missing.

Comment: Off course: its part of a reservation-system: when a reservation is starting on a certain date; it can only last as long as the same group_id is applicable.

Comment: So, if I get it right, each date gets assigned a single group_id, and you want to track from $date how many more days the same $group_id is registered?

Comment: That's correct; with one big caveat: not every date is present in the table; if not present in table the group_id would be the $default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Erik's answer, but using only a single database query:

```
function getConsecutiveDays($date, $default = 1, $max = 99)
{
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
    $results = getConsecutiveDaysFromDatabase($date, $max);
    $result = reset($results);
    $initial_group_id = false;
    $n = 0;
    while ($max--)  {
        $day = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        if ($result && $result->date === $day) {
            $group_id = (int) $result->group_id;
            $result = next($results);
        } else {
            $group_id = (int) $default;
        }
        if (!$initial_group_id) {
            $initial_group_id = $group_id;
        } elseif ($initial_group_id === $group_id) {
            $n++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
        $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }
    return $n;
}

function getConsecutiveDaysFromDatabase(DateTimeInterface $date, $max = 99)
{
    $database = new PDO(/* your connection details here */);
    $statement = $database->prepare('
        SELECT date, group_id
        FROM some_table
        WHERE date >= :date
        ORDER BY date ASC
        LIMIT :max;
    ');
    $statement->bindValue(':date', $date->format('Y-m-d'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindValue(':max', (int) $max, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Output:

```
var_dump(getConsecutiveDays('2017-12-12'));
int(3)
var_dump(getConsecutiveDays('2017-12-16'));
int(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very straight-forward and not at all efficient approach; but it should clarify the idea.

It's also mostly using pseudo-code and non-existent methods that hopefully make it clear what they do...

```
function getConsecutiveDays(\DateTimeInterface $date, $default = 1, $max = 99)
{       
   $initialGroup = findGroupForDate($date);
   $date = $date->modify('+1 days');
   $n = 1;

   while( $n < $max ) {
     $groupOnDate = findGroupForDate($date);
     // default check
     if($groupOnDate === null) {
       $groupOnDate = $default;
     }
     // if this is a different group; no longer consecutive
     if($groupOnDate !== $initialGroup) {
       return $n;
     }
     // count as consecutive
     $n++;
     $date = $date->modify('+1 days');
   }   
   return $n;
}

function findGroupForDate(\DateTimeInterface $date) {
  $rows = query("select group_id from some_table where date = " . $date->format('Y-m-d'));
  if(count($rows) == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  return $rows[0]['group_id'];
}
```